# Who / what has access to delete cookies?

Tags: cookies

I'm experiencing an odd issue lately where I'm frequently being logged out of YouTube, but not from other Google services. Upon further investigation, it looks like the SID cookie which is used to login to *.youtube.com occasionally disappears from my machine, despite it having a fairly long expiration (in years). This leads me to believe that something is deleting the cookie, though it certainly isn't me (I'm not clearing the cookie cache or anything of that sort). I've also checked my Chrome extensions and nothing seems to be suspicious. Any other ideas what may be deleting these cookies? I'm assuming the only site who might have access to those cookies is YouTube itself.

Comment: Have you tried using another browser, maybe Firefox, or Opera?

Comment: As trying another browser is a great idea, you could also try clearing your cache.